# Problems with update DryIoc and automapper

Tags: c#, automapper, dryioc

I have updated DryIoc from version 4.8.8 to 5.4.1 and Automapper from version 10.1.1 to 12.0.1. Previously, I registered Automapper using the following method:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(options =>
            {
                options.ForAllMaps((obj, options) => options.ForAllMembers(o => o.Condition((src, dest, member) => member != null)));
            }, typeof(Responce<>));
```

However, the ForAllMaps() method has been moved:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(options =>
            {
                options.Internal().ForAllMaps((obj, options) => options.ForAllMembers(o => o.Condition((src, dest, member) => member != null)));
            }, typeof(Responce<>));
```

And now when I call the mapper, I get the following error:

> Error.WaitForScopedServiceIsCreatedTimeoutExpired; message: DryIoc has
> waited for the creation of the scoped or singleton service by the
> "other party" for the 3000 ticks without the completion.  You may
> call `exception.TryGetDetails(container)` to get the details of the
> problematic service registration. The error means that either the
> "other party" is the parallel thread which has started but is unable
> to finish the creation of the service in the provided amount of time.
> Or more likely the "other party"  is the same thread and there is an
> undetected recursive dependency or  the scoped service creation is
> failed with the exception and the exception was catched but you are
> trying to resolve the failed service again.  For all those reasons
> DryIoc has a timeout to prevent the infinite waiting.  You may change
> the default timeout via
> `Scope.WaitForScopedServiceIsCreatedTimeoutTicks=NewNumberOfTicks`

What is the correct way to register Automapper in DryIoc?

Comment: What's `ForAllMaps` got to do with anything? If you remove that, you have the same problem, right? :)